# Trouble with SO on MCP23S18 spi gpio expander

Tags: spi, gpio, expander

I am unable to get a signal out of the slave out (SO) line of an MCP23S18
For those not familiar it is a slave SPI gpio expander.

Clocking in 32 bits, as it goes 16 bits set up, 8 bit opcode, 8 bit intended register address, then data...

In the attached pics you can see my scope, having only a 2 channel scope:
- the top pic blue line clock, yellow SO
- the bottom pic the blue line SI, again the yellow is SO

The odd think is the SO line looks like it is a combination of the clock and the SI data...

For giggles I tried pulling up (and down) the SO line but that just moves the same waveform up to vdd or down to ground.

I've checked and rechecked my wiring, but I suppose anything is possibly the cause.
I've tried a second MCP23S18 with the same result.

From what I understand the SO is a tri state line, that is driven from the slave so it seems to be an issue with the slave.

What I failed to get a pic of is the CS line, though I did scope it to make sure it was going low in time.  Though from the scope it does seem that the slave might not be alerted to the CS and leaving the SO at high impedance.

I'd be grateful for advise to resolve this issue

[image: SPI clock in blue, SO in yellow]

[image: SPI SI in blue, SO in yellow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I now realize or have learned that the SO is a tri state line, having to be controlled by any or all other slaves, slaves need to disconnect it from the circuit when their CS line has not been selected.
Here I was mistaken in expecting a signal from the slave and the line remained in the don't care state.